# ERROR StatusLogger Error processing element BatchDelivery ([appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND

Tags: log4j2

I was trying to send logs to elastic search but my log4j2 file shows this error. Can anyone help me out of this. Thanks in advance.

TestLogger.java

public class TestLogger {

```
 private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TestLogger.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logger.info("Hello World !");

        logger.info("Hello ElasticSearch !");
    }
}
```

log4j2.xml

```
<Appenders>

    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{ABSOLUTE}][%-5p][%-25c][%t] %m%n" />
    </Console>

        <BatchDelivery batchSize="10000" deliveryInterval="1000">
        <NoSql name="elasticsearchAppender">
        <Elasticsearch url="http://10.162.205.175:9200/_bulk" index="data_upload_assignment" type="log4j2">
        </Elasticsearch>
        </NoSql>
        </BatchDelivery>

</Appenders>

<loggers>
    <!-- <logger name="com.ait.TestLogger">
        <appender-ref ref="elasticsearchAppender" />
    </logger>-->

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="elasticsearchAppender" />
    </root>
</loggers>
```